# Django Translations compilemessages Error: 'msgstr' is not a valid Python format string

Tags: python, django, translation

I have the following error due to % sign. Any idea how to overcome this error?

django-admin.py compilemessages -l tr

processing file django.po in /.../locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES

CommandError: Execution of msgfmt failed: /.../locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po:139: 'msgstr' is not a valid Python format string, unlike 'msgid'. Reason: In the directive number 1, the character '{' is not a valid conversion specifier.

/.../locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po:146: 'msgstr' is not a valid Python format string, unlike 'msgid'. Reason: In the directive number 1, the character '{' is not a valid conversion specifier.
msgfmt: found 2 fatal errors

models.py

```
def get_full_title(self):
    return _(u"{discounted_price} TL for {original_price} TL worth of {product_name} at {place_name} {locality} {city} ({discount_percentage}% off)").format(
        discounted_price=int(self.discounted_price),
        original_price=int(self.original_price),
        product_name=self.product.name,
        place_name=self.product.place.name,
        locality=self.product.place.locality,
        city=self.product.place.get_city_display(),
        discount_percentage=self.get_rounded_discount_percentage(),
    )


def get_short_title(self):
    return _(u"{product_name} at {place_name} ({discount_percentage}% off)").format(
        product_name=self.product.name,
        place_name=self.product.place.name,
        discount_percentage=self.get_rounded_discount_percentage(),
    )
```

django.po

```
#: deals/models.py:169
#, python-format, python-brace-format
msgid ""
"{discounted_price} TL for {original_price} TL worth of {product_name} at "
"{place_name} {locality} {city} ({discount_percentage}% off)"
msgstr ""
"{discounted_price} TL for {original_price} TL worth of {product_name} at "
"{place_name} {locality} {city} (%{discount_percentage} indirim)"

#: deals/models.py:181
#, python-format, python-brace-format
msgid "{product_name} at {place_name} ({discount_percentage}% off)"
msgstr "{product_name} at {place_name} (%{discount_percentage} indirim)"
```

Answer (score 13):

You can the escape the `%` by doubling it up `%%`